# After creating a team connection with NetworkManager, on reboot disappear with strange results

Tags: networking, networkmanager, bonding

I have created, on Fedora server a team connection using networkManager

```
nmcli con add type team con-name team0 ifname team0 config /usr/share/doc/teamd/example_configs/random.conf
nmcli con add type team-slave ifname enp1s0 master team0
nmcli con add type team-slave ifname enp7s0 master team0
nmcli connection modify team0 ethernet.mac-address 01:02:03:04:05:06
nmcli connection up team0
nmcli connection delete ethernet-enp1s0
nmcli connection delete ethernet-enp7s0
```

The command is simple, I have create the team0 connection, add two network cards(enp1s0 and enp7s0), then I forced team0 to use mac address 01:02:03:04:05:06(is faked..only for security reasons) to get same hostname
and ip from dhcp.
Works fine, but on reboot...

```
nmcli conn show
Cable connection 1      3bce3e28-47a0-365b-8290-eda5ff3f7c7b  ethernet  nm-team 
team0                   6f97a64b-f341-4cbe-b001-d8bb3faa8768  team      --      
team-slave-enp1s0       cc6f2e64-8f38-4a83-b1c3-226e22943751  ethernet  --      
team-slave-enp7s0       ecdefac9-779b-4c86-838b-46e69132c94b  ethernet  --
```

Trying to activate team0 give me this error

nmcli conn up team0

```
nm-team failed to create resources: Failed to create team master interface 'nm-team' for 'team0': wrong-type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, this line

```
nmcli connection modify team0 ethernet.mac-address 01:02:03:04:05:06
```

make the system a little confused and rename the enp1s0(physical) 
to team0(virtual).
Removing this line and redoing the other works fine even on reboot, to get the same ip from dhcp I use this configuration way

```
host myhost {
hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
fixed-address 192.168.0.12;
ddns-hostname "myhost";
ddns-ttl 31536000;
}

host myhost-2 {
hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
fixed-address 192.168.0.12;
ddns-hostname "myhost";
ddns-ttl 31536000;
}
```

Comment: That's probably because this team master profile is stored in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*`. These files are also regarded by udev, so if you specify both a MAC address and an interface name, udev will rename your device. I guess, you could disable that udev behavior (somehow, check interface naming on Fedora). Or you could tell NetworkManager to not write ifcfg- files (`main.plugins=keyfile,ifcfg-rh` in `man NetworkManager.conf`). I think this is a udev bug, because it shouldn't do this for a team profile.